# How to make class static variable thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a class like so:

```
class Test
{
private:
    Test() {}
    static bool is_done;
    static void ThreadFunction();
public:
    static void DoSomething();
}


bool Test::is_done = true;

void Test::DoSomething()
{
    std::thread t_thread(Test::ThreadFunction);

    while (true) {
        if (is_done) {
            //do something else
            is_done = false;
        }

        if (/*something happened*/) { break; }
    }

    // Finish thread.
    t_thread.join();
}

void Test::ThreadFunction()
{
    while (true) {
        if (/*something happened*/) {
            is_done = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In main I then just call Test::DoSomething(); Is variable 'is_done' in this case thread safe? If its not how can I make reading it safe?

Comment: are you going to wait for is_done to be true/false somewhere?

Comment: @RichardHodges I am in Test::DoSomething()

Comment: You can throw a static mutex in there to make it thread safe

Comment: so it's a timed latch?

Comment: The only way to make anything threadsafe (static or otherwise) without atomics or locks if to make it immutable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is global variable 'is_done' in this case thread safe?

No. `static` does not imply thread-safe.

---

> If its not how can I make reading it safe?

You should use [`std::atomic<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic):

```
class Test
{
private:
    Test() {}
    static std::atomic<bool> is_done;
    static void ThreadFunction();
public:
    static void DoSomething();
}

std::atomic<bool> Test::is_done{true};
```

Comment: Note that making it `atomic` may not necessarily work if you're doing multiple reads/writes in one sensitive operation, e.g. `if (Test::is_done) {Test::is_done = false; ...}`

Comment: should probably use lock_guard for such operations.

Answer (score 3):

If the type is [TriviallyCopyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) then you can use [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) like

```
static std::atomic<bool> is_done;
```

If your type is not TriviallyCopyable then you can use a [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)

---

Do not that `std::atomic` operations can be optimized away.  If you have something like

```
static std::atomic<bool> is_done;
...
is_done = true;
is_done = false;
```

The compiler can cut out `is_done = true;`  For mor on this see JF Bastien's [“No Sane Compiler Would Optimize Atomics"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB57wIf9W1k)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not allowed to comment yet, but have you tried using atomics?

e.g. `std::atomic<bool>`